# "Negotiate with someone for something" or "negotiate with someone to get something"?

Tags: word-usage, collocations

Could you tell me which of the following sentences sounds the most natural?

> We will **negotiate with** the company as hard as we can **to get** a better deal.
>
> We will **negotiate with** the company as hard as we can **for** a better deal.

If both sentences sound off, then what would a native English speaker say to communicate the idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use ‘to get’, as the “better deal” doesn’t represent the actual thing you are negotiating **for**.

It might also be worth mentioning that one does not “negotiate *for* a deal”, but “negotiates a deal”.